# Jenkins Performance Plugin for Jmeter- edit Performance Report Table

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-plugins, performance-testing

I'm using Jenkins Performance Plugin for Jmeter (version 3.1) for integrating and reporting Jmeter results. In the Performance Report (of specific build) I get the Performance Breakdown table (and Response time graph)- as described in the documentation- http://jenkinsci.github.io/performance-plugin/Reporting.html.
**Is there a way to customize the columns in the Report table?** I wish to **add a 'Throughput' column**- as in the Aggregate Report of Jmeter (the results file is in an XML format)

Answer (score 1):

Just noticed this comment in corresponding [Jenkins Issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18576):

> released in 3.8

Comment: But as per the issue comments, the feature is not implemented yet. The issue in reopen state as of 2020 September.

Answer (score 0):

Since resolution to this issue is yet to be implemented. Here is a way to get the same report from another platform CLIF runtime if that is fine with your requirement.
I think, You can use [CLIF Performance Testing](https://plugins.jenkins.io/clif-performance-testing/) plugin instead of Performance trend plugin which regenerates a report with the throughput column as given below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eEJQ.png)